# Spread operator in a function return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, use-state

I am having some trouble interpreting what is going on in a specific piece of code in reactJS and was wondering if anyone is able to point me in the right direction.

```
const [allPokemons, setAllPokemons] = useState([]);

  const getAllPokemons = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=649&offset=0'
    );
    const data = await res.json();

    function createPokemonObject(results) {
      results.forEach(async (pokemon) => {
        const res = await fetch(
          `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon.name}`
        );
        const data = await res.json();

        setAllPokemons((currentList) => [...currentList, data]);
        await allPokemons.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      });
    }
    createPokemonObject(data.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPokemons();
  }, []);
```

I'm specifically confused about this line of code:

```
setAllPokemons((currentList) => [...currentList, data]);
```

I have usually seen the spread operator used in the parameter but not in this manner. If anyone can shed some light on what is going on here would be great or point me in the direction to look into this usage more deeply.

Here's my codebase if you need more context: https://github.com/lojickse7en/pokedex-app

Comment: "Adding" `data` to the array by creating a new array. Similar to `currentList.concat(data)`. You will find more about the [spread syntax here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. Generally speaking, particularly when something's name is known, looking it up is the quickest approach, or just playing in the REPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the spread operator is used to make a copy of the list and add additional elements.  So, if your `currentList` is `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`, your arrow function, `((currentList) => [...currentList, 'buz'])` unpacks to `((currentList) => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'buz'])`.  The newly created array is returned.  The difference between just appending to an array (`currentList.push('buz')`), and creating it the way you see in your example, is that in the first case you create a side-effect of changing the original array.  This isn't the end of the world, but a tenet of Functional Programming is the idea that pure functions shouldn't produce side-effects (changes outside of their function body).  Using the spread operator as shown above allows us to return a *new* array instead of altering the existing one.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the extra info about side effects. I'm assuming if there is not an initial value of currentList, it will only include 'data'? Or 'buz' in your example `(currentList) => ['buz']`?

Comment: Yup, as long as the list was initialized as an empty array (`[]`).  FWIW, you can use this same syntax to create new objects or to over-write certain object properties `const newObj = { ...oldObj, newProp: 'value', otherProp: 'otherValue };`

Answer (score 0):

It just means to construct a new list with the current list and add "data" to it.

e.g.

```
> a = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> [ ...a, 4,5 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is spreading the values of an iterable, and the second passed value adds more data to the existing list. e.g push or concat.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = [...a, 2,6,8]
```

will result to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 8]`